# Is there a way to get a connection from wildfly connection pool?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, querydsl

I'm trying to work with Wildfly 10.0 application server and Querydsl. My problem is Querydsl need a connection to evaulate the SQL query. The only way I can get a connection is shown in this code snippet.

```
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
@Singleton
public class ServiceTest {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/datasources/postgresDS")
    private DataSource ds;

    public Memeber getMemeberById(final int id) {
        try {
            Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
            Memeber member = new SQLQuery<Memeber>(new Configuration(new PostgreSQLTemplates()))
                    .select(Projections.bean(Memeber.class, QMember.member.id.as(Memeber.ID),
                            QMember.member.name.as(Memeber.NAME)))
                    .from(QMember.member).where(QMember.member.id.eq(id)).fetchOne();
            connection.close();
            return member;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

This solution is works but create some problems. If all connection in use the ds.getConnection() throws javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/postgresDS exception.

Is there any way to access the Wildfly connection pool to get a connection? and after the SQL runs return to the pool the connection? I don't want to implement a connection pooling mechanism if the Wildfly have one.

Comment: Nope, I want to try something new. I used JPA about two years long.

Comment: Thanks your answer @BalusC. I understand your opinion, but I looking for an alternative solution instead of JPA with Hibernate or EclipseLink and Querydsl looks great. In this way I still need Hibernate and the entity manager.

Comment: Maybe I missed the point of it and my boses missed it too. But in the past we have numerous problems with JPA and Hibernate (eg: hardly readable queries, chaching problems, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the question. When `ds.getConnection()` called it gives a connection from the pool because it call `org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool#getConnection` method. After the bean method ended and the `connection.close()` called the `org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool#returnConnection` method return the connection to the pool. So the `connection.close()` not close the connection. Important to call `connection.close()` becasue the connection never return to the pool.